# Play framework 2 add custom compilation task

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have a play 2.5 project and I'd like to execute some code at compilation time.

Specifically, I want to generate previews for large images that will be served :

There are jpeg files in /resources/images/

And I want to generate previews and put them in /public/images/

I already have the java class to do this, say :

```
public class PreviewGenerator {
 public static void generate(String sourceDir, String targetDir) {
  //do things
 }
}
```

Now, how can I tell play to execute PreviewGenerator.generate(.....) before/after compiling ?